# SharePoint Permission on Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath

MOSS 2007 standard (no forms services)

I want to submit a form to a Form Library so that after the form is submitted, only the owner of the site and library can edit the form.  Anybody can add or view, owners can edit or delete.

I have created a customer Permission Level that only allows *Add Items* and *View Items*, and trying to submit an InfoPath 2007 form to the library will successfully add a document to the library, but give the following error message to the user:

> Error submitting the form.  You can
>   save a copy to your machine and
>   process it manually later.
>   **details:**
>
> InfoPath cannot submit the form.
>
> An error occurred while the form was
>   being submitted.
>
> The form cannot be submitted to the following location:
>   http://space/xx/yyyy/zz/Test/TEST-276-2009-08-17.xml
>   There is a problem with the Web
>   server. Make sure the Web server
>   exists, try again later or contact the
>   Web server administrator.

So the users of course try again and again to submit the file, but it is already there.

If I allow *Edit Items* into the Permission Level it works as expected, but the business rules don't allow normal users to edit any files including their own.

Can this be accomplished without other intervention such as a custom workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointinfopath/thread/7c02a4e6-39ce-4616-ad2b-f8559a7527d4) is an MSDN forums topic that is very similar to yours. Basically, the result was that MS says SharePoint does a checkout/checkin once the form is submitted, which requires Edit permissions. A further post by Clayton Cobb outlines a possible workaround for the problem.

Comment: Thank you for at least pointing out why.  I am afraid the workaround does leave open avenues, so it won't work for our situation.

Comment: I was thinking about this last night and thought of something much simpler, but haven't had a chance to try it. Why not try turning off document checkout (and possibly document versioning) on the list to see if that helps fix the problem?

Comment: Document checkout and versioning are both off already.  That is why it is so frustrating that InfoPath chooses to check-in.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things we did - and it worked for us - although it doesn't "officially" prevent editing....

I allowed editing to be enabled - so submission worked as needed.  Then, I created a view of the library that removed the edit options (believe it's document name without the edit menu - you'll see it) I then made this new view the default view.  Now, a savvy user would know to go into an alternate view to access the edit options - but this keeps 99% of my casual end users from causing problems.

Not airtight - but for us it has worked well.